# Confirmation of back navigation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I only want to confirm back navigation for one of the the view I have. The specific view is a UICollectionViewController. I know my exact coding in the if statement isn't right. I'm not quite sure how to do it. Fill in the blanks for me?

CollectionViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    BOOL isThisViewACollectionView = YES;

}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {
        // back button was pressed.  We know this is true because self is no longer
        // in the navigation stack.
        if (isThisViewACollectionView) {
            UIAlertView *cameraAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Camera Not Available" message:@"The camera feature isn't available on your device." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [cameraAlertView show];
        }
    }else{
        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with the logic,
The following statement is called when you already dropped the viewcontroller

```
   if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {

    }
```

So a better solution would be to hold a value somewhere "above (before)" viewWillDisappear which knows if the viewcontroller is uicollectionView (let's say a BOOL)
and assuming this value is true alert the user (filling your missing code).

Comment: Could you provide me with an example?

Comment: set a BOOL value in your viewDidLoad - for example BOOL isThisViewACollectionView = YES;

and your missing code is if (isThisViewACollectionView) {
            //an alert will appear
        }

Comment: Updated Code. It says in the viewWillDissapear that isThisViewACollectionView is an undeclared identifier